# Create a return type based on table-valued function

Tags: linq-to-sql, orm, user-defined-functions, return-type

I often have a group of table-valued functions that return datasets with same structure (same column names, types and order).

If I just drag the functions into the Linq2Sql designer, the designer will create a new anonymous result type for each of the functions, and the functions will not be compatible result-wise.

To tell the designer the functions have the same result type, I need to drag the functions onto an existing Linq2Sql class.

That is fine, but I have to manually create the class every time (insert a new table in the designer area, press <kbd>Insert</kbd> many times to insert columns, type in column names, client-side data types and server-side data types). This can be really time-consuming if there are many columns and many functions.

**Is there a way to tell the designer to automatically create an entity (table class) by looking at a table-valued function**, so that I can then drag the rest of the functions onto that entity?

My current workaround is:

- Create a view on the server:

  ```sql
  create view dbo.stupid_linq as select * from dbo.FunctionIWant(bogus_params);
  ```
- Drag that view to the designer, which creates an entity.
- Unlink the entity from the database by deleting its `Source`.
- Rename the entity.
- Delete the view on the server.
- Drag the table-valued functions onto the entity.

Comment: According to me I think you have to create dummy tables in DB and make complex type of multiple tables which you can use without define the class again and again.

Comment: Actually I think your workaround is pretty good. All you need is to add TOP 0 into your dummy view (to prevent it ever getting used) and you're set. Nothing wrong with posting it as an answer in lieu of anything better